# How can I check associated attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have the following relationships

`User` **has_many** `Clients` **through** `ClientMemberships`

`Client` **has_many** `Projects`

`Project` **belongs_to** `Client`

Given a specific user. What is the best way to find all clients for a user which have a specific project ID.

I don't want to iterate through all of the projects and check each with ruby, rather than to use some SQL to do the job with eager loading in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@user.clients.joins(:projects).where("projects.id = ?", your_project_id)
```

Comment: since i fixed my answer, i guess your answer was the first one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
  def clients_for_project_id(project_id)
    clients.joins(:projects).where(projects: { id: project_id })
  end
end
```

Comment: on the other hand, you have a not hard-coded way of writing "where" statement :)

Comment: Though, as far as I can see here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/where ( example: User.joins(:posts).where({ posts: { published: true } }) ), you should have "where(projects:" and not "where(project:".

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple, use a `joins` for doing the condition on the other table, and the `inculdes` for the eager loading.

```
user.clients
  .joins(:projects)
  .includes(:projects)
  .where(projects: { id: project_id })
```